# MVC Search Bar throwing NullException when property being searched is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, lambda, nullreferenceexception

I am implementing a search bar using the asp.net tutorial

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString = null)
    {
        var viewModels = new List<ScheduleViewModel>();
        foreach (var schedule in db.Schedule)
            viewModels.Add(GetViewModelFromSchedule(schedule));

        //--vm for viewModel
        var vm = from s in viewModels
                 select s;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            vm = vm.Where(s =>
                s.Description.Contains(searchString));   
        }
         //--CODE FOR SORT ORDER THAT I LEFT OUT BECAUSE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN ABOVE
        return View(vm.ToList());
    }
```

My HTML looks like this in the View

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")" >

<input type="search" name="searchString"  />
<input type="submit" value="Filter" />

</form>
```

When I go through the debug and hover over s.Description it shows me null. 
The searchString is passed through just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Filter out the items where `Description` is `null` first

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        vm = vm.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Description) &&
            s.Description.Contains(searchString));   
    }
```